# Does a timer-triggered Azure function execute if an instance of the function is already executing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App with the `[TimerTrigger(...)]` attribute, which is scheduled to execute every morning.

Suppose you manually execute the function via the Function Menu Blade -> Code + Test -> Test/Run, as shown at the bottom of this message.  What happens if this manual execution of the function is still running when the time specified in the `TimerTrigger` attribute arrives?

1. Will the manual execution be interrupted by the timer-triggered execution?
2. Will the manual execution *prevent* the timer from triggering a new execution of the function?
3. Or will a new instance of the function be kicked off when the timer triggers it, running in parallel with the existing manual execution?

[image]

Comment: [These docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks) seem to indicate that only one instance can be running at a time, and a second attempt will wait till it can acquire the lock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the same azure function at the same time. You can add a bool if you want to prevent the execution of the azure function if it is currently running:

```
public class AzureFunction()
{
   private static bool _isRunning = false;

   [FunctionName("Function1")]
   public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 9 * * *")] 
      if (_isRunning)
      {
         //an instance is already running, lets not continue
         return;
      }
      _isRunning = true;

   //work is being done

   //after work is done
   _isRunning = false;
}
```

Say you have a Timer that goes off every minute, but your code takes 2 minutes to run. The timer will kick off every minute regardless of if the previous run is done or not.

If you set your TimerTrigger to run at a daily time, a manual run will not interrupt or cause an issue to your daily run *but you can still do a manual run during your timed trigger*. Example of the one above will run every day at 9:30am.

Comment: Thanks.  What if you disable the function?  Will that prevent the function from being timer-triggered while at the same time not killing the manually-executing function instance?

Comment: Yes if you disable the function it cannot run from the timed trigger. You can however still run that function on your local machine for testing, but the deployed version will not run once disabled.

Comment: Sorry I missed part of your question. You can disable the function and the Timed trigger won't run, but you can still test it in the portal with the manual Test/Run. You can also test it on your local machine in say a C# app by running it there too.

Comment: That solution doesn't work across multiple instances, you would need to use something more robust than simple statics if you have scaled out. Moving the flag to Blob or Storage Table or DB could solve this however.

Answer (score 0):

It won't trigger again if there is an outstanding invocation still running:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/84